# How do I maximize the Size of a GraphicsView in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I'm new to .NET MAUI and have a simple question:

How do I use all the remaining space within a layout for a GraphicsView?

I tried `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` in combination with `VerticalOptions="Fill"`. But it only works if I insert the GraphicsView directly into the ContentPage.
As soon as I use a layout to put the GraphicsView in it, it doesn't show up. The only way to show this is to use height and width requirements with concrete numbers.

Why doesn't my attempt work and how do I solve this?

This doesn't work:

```xml
<ContentPage>    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <drawable:MyDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <GraphicsView Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
            BackgroundColor="Purple"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

This works, but with fixed size:

```xml
<ContentPage>    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <drawable:MyDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <GraphicsView Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
            BackgroundColor="Purple"
            HeightRequest="200"
            WidthRequest="200" />/>
        <Label
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [StackLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout) is unconstrained in one direction, either vertically or horizontally. Therefore, you won't be able to use the `Fill` option to take up all the available space in that particular direction.

If you want to take the entire space that is available, you should use a Grid instead:

```xml
<ContentPage>    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <drawable:MyDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,auto">
        <GraphicsView Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
            Grid.Row="0"
            BackgroundColor="Purple"
            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
            VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="Hello, World!"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
            FontSize="32"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Here, the first row of the Grid will take up as much space as possible using the *Star* option, while the second row only takes up the space required to fit the Label using the *auto* option for the row height.

***Note** that the `*AndExpand` LayoutOptions are deprecated in MAUI, they shouldn't be used anymore.*

Comment: In the documentation, where can I find such layout related Information? (Vertical or horizontal layouts don't support stretching?
Without diving into the layout process: I intuitively thought the VerticalStackLayout would use the remaining Space (if only one element uses the fill option).

With more elements set to "Fill" is would assume that the remaining space is divided equally b the number of elements using "Fill".

Comment: It's indeed a little hidden in the Xamarin.Forms to MAUI migration documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/layouts

Answer (score 0):

You can set the StackLayout like this with `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"`.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <drawable:GraphicsDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Border
        BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
        Stroke="Blue"
        StrokeShape="Rectangle"
        StrokeThickness="4"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <GraphicsView
            Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}" />
        </Border>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label
        Text="Hello, World!"
        SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
        FontSize="32"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The `*AndExpand`-Options are deprecated in MAUI. They only still exist for compatibility but will eventually be removed, AFAIK.

Comment: I assume this works because the GraphicsView is placed inside a Border